# How to train a LSTM on a sequence of dates?

Tags: python, datetime, machine-learning, time-series, lstm

if i wanted to train an lstm to predict the next date in a sequence of dates, how would i do that since lstm require a scaled value?

example of data:

| date | next date |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-05-12 | 2012-05-13 |
| 2012-05-13 | 2012-05-19 |
| 2012-05-19 | 2012-05-20 |
| 2012-05-20 | 2012-05-22 |
| 2012-05-22 | 2012-05-26 |
| 2012-05-26 | 2012-05-27 |
| 2012-05-27 | 2012-05-30 |
| 2012-05-30 | 2012-06-12 |
| 2012-06-12 | 2012-05-19 |
| 2012-06-19 | 2012-06-25 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You could hand over the date split into three inputs:** One would then be the year, the other the month, and the last the day. While normalizing your inputs definitely makes sense, however I would not entirely agree with your "LSTM requires".

Day and month are already limited to a range of values which can be scaled

- day (1 - 31)
- month (1 - 12)

For year you need to make an educated assumption based on your application. So that year can then also be transferred to a scaled value. Judging from your data, it might be that year is constant at 2012 and it is not needed to begin with.

- year (2012 - 2013(?))

*Note:* Ask yourself whether you give the neural network enough system information to be able to predict the next date - meaning, is there already enough of a pattern in your data? Otherwise you might end up training a random predictor.

Comment: the data contains many years so the year is relevant. thank you for the quick answer!